# Discord.js v13 why is this code not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I wanted to make my bot say whatever I tell it to by using a command. I have the code copied from other parts of my bot and it is working there yet here it just doesn't and I can't understand why. There are no error messages.
Here's my code:

```js
const { Permissions } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'say',
    description: "Sprawia że coś mówię.",
    execute(message, args)
    {
        let text = args.join(" ").slice(22);
        if(text)
        {
            message.channel.send(text)
        }
        else 
        {
            message.reply('test')//show correct usage
        }
    }
}
```

(const {Permissions} will be used later so don't worry about it being there)
Also you can see what it looks like on discord: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8BxX.png).

Comment: Did you add the command to your `client.commands` collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is working exactly how you have programmed it. Take a look at this line:

```js
let text = args.join(" ").slice(22);
```

Assuming your `args` in the test case `"rp say xd"` are just supposed to be `"xd"`, the above code is entirely wrong. The code combines the args, separating them with spaces, and then gets a substring of that starting from the 22nd character. In other words, for `text` to be anything other than an empty string, your args would have to be over 22 characters long (`"rp say xdddddddddddddddddddd!"` would make `text` equal just the ending `"!"`).

Because `text` is always an empty string for args under 22 characters long, you are basically just doing `if ("")`, which is the same as doing `if (false)`. This means your `else` statement will always run, unless your `args` are over 22 characters long combined.

To fix this, do something like this instead:

```js
let text = args.join(" ");
```

Or, if you meant to make your bot only use the first 22 characters of args provided to it:

```js
let text = args.join(" ").slice(0, 22); //.slice(startIndex, endIndexExclusive)
```